Intended travel date already started but visa is still in process
My intended travel date is tomorrow, September 3rd, but my visa is still being processed at the embassy. It was initially refused, and I appealed. The embassy has since requested that I resubmit my passport. Will they issue the visa, or will I need to submit a new flight ticket or itinerary? Thank you for your help

You need to follow their instructions. No one will be able to tell you anything of significance about your situation.
